# Print lines containing an exact word, not regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script and I would like to print all lines containing a word, but only if it is at the end of a line. So given a file like this:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./12/2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./12/1.txt
717c41ff4049b0e8cbdc7ec7e49ad021  ./1
```

and the given word equal to "./1" I would like to print only the line:

```
717c41ff4049b0e8cbdc7ec7e49ad021  ./1
```

I'd simply use grep for that, but my problem is that the words may contain dots so I need to have the `-F` option, but then I am unsure how to secure that the printed lines contain the word at the end of the line, as I can't use line anchors. What seems to be working is using `grep -Fw`, but I am not convinced that this exactly what I'm looking for as `-w` option means `--word-regexp` and I don't want regex. Does the`-F` option disable the regex matching in `-w`? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: `man grep`, and look at the `-F` (`--fixed-strings`) option.

Comment: Thanks @larsks! I edited the post, this is indeed the answer to my previous question, but not exactly what I was looking for as the question was badly asked.

Comment: why not just use 'grep -E "1$" file.txt '. What is the reason you cant use a regex? That would work perfectly according to your example.

Comment: It doesn't work with this example. The second line is also selected.